# Python rounding 3.25 to 3.2

Tags: python, string, rounding

How would I get the number 3.25 to round down to 3.2 in python.

I tried using string formatting to round to 1 digit but it only rounds up to 3.3, not down to 3.2.

Comment: show us the code of your attempt

Comment: Are you using python2?

Comment: You can use multiplication, division, and [`math.floor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.floor).